# Online database connection via phpMyAdmin with a local PHP script

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am creating an application that requires an online database to store information and query from it when needed. I have since created a online SQL server on a free hosting site and am connected to it via phpMyAdmin. I have the host name, username and password but I was wondering how I would use a php script I created locally and run it on the online database? The free hosting site does not have any visible upload options for files.

Furthermore, how would I execute this php script from Xcode?

Comment: I am not sure if your free hosting give you remote access of database but if they do, you can use it by adding SQL info. For file upload you can use FTP or check file manager on hosting. You have to install server for php execution. You may use MAMP for easy start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really don't understand what you are trying to do, since you already created the script locally. Just replace the server name, username, password of your local script to the one given by the online SQL server and upload it through FTP. That should work

Comment: I get an error :

Could not parse response code.
Server Reply: [
5.5.49-0ubuntu0.14.04.1�es4HJ|Q_���kzF.R5Mf<55Hmysql_native_password. Please contact your web hosting service provider for assistance.

Could it be because the hosting service does not support FTP?